# What cause to button working like a submit button?

Tags: html, spring, model-view-controller, view

I have tow buttons inside my form,
one is a submit and the second is a simple button (like cancel button that close the dialog).

**Code:**

```
<dialog id="addSubjectDialog" style="width:20%; height:25%;">
         <div style="width:100%; hegit:20%;"><h2 style="font-size:100%;"><fmt:message key="add_subject_dialog_title" /></h2></div>
            <form action="addSubject" method="post" >   
         <div style="width:100%; hegit:20%;">
            <h2 style="font-size:100%;"><input id="SubjectName" name="SubjectName" style="font-size:100%;text-align: right;"></input> <fmt:message key="insert_subject_name" /> </h2>
         </div>


         <div style="height: 60px;margin-top:5% ;">

             <fmt:message key="save" var="save"/>
             <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" style=" float: left; width:40%; "value="${save}"></input>
             <button id="cancelSubSubjectDialog"   class="btn btn-warning" style="float: right; width: 40%;" ><fmt:message key="cancel" /></button>
         </form>
         </div>


        </dialog>
```

the code of the cancel button is in a script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


   window.onload = function () {

    document.getElementById("cancelSubjectDialog").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            document.getElementById("addSubjectDialog").close();
          });
    document.getElementById("saveSubjectDialog").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();



        document.getElementById("addSubjectDialog").close();
      });

       }


   function ShowDialog(dialogName) { 
       selectList();
        document.getElementById(dialogName).showModal();
    }

   </script>
```

In the onLoad function I set the cancel button action.

*I have another dialog in my page that do the same things and include cancel and save buttons too, and it's working fine.

When I click on the cancel button the "addSubject" is called;
What is wrong in my code? Why does the action is called if I click on cancel button too?

Comment: Where does your code actually tell the buttons what they are supposed to do? The default action of your form is `addSubject` and I don't see anything that would tell those buttons to do otherwise

Comment: I will edit the question...

Comment: It looks to me like you have both buttons doing the same thing in your code... is that right?

Comment: I dont know thats not my meaninig... whath should I do?

Comment: Erm. ***not*** have the buttons do the same thing?

Comment: No, one save the dialog details, ("submit"). and the another only close the dialog without save the details.